# How to enable Adobe Connect screen sharing

Tags: virtualbox, vmware, teamviewer

I'm using Adobe Connect 9.1 for the meetings and I often have to demonstrate something from my Linux Mint 17.2 machine. Unfortunately, Adobe Connect AddIn doesn't support screen sharing on Linux. It used to support in version 8, but for some reason they decided Linux users are not their target group. I would personally use some alternative such as Google hangout, but my company officially use Adobe connect for meetings, so I'm stuck with it.

I'm wondering if there is any solution for this problem. I thought that it might be possible to have VirtualBox with Windows OS, and use it for screen sharing of the Linux host. However, it didn't work.

Did anyone try something similar? For me, it would also work to use other Windows 7 laptop on the same LAN and access Linux through something like Team Viewer, so I can share screen in Adobe Connect.

I know it is possible to share through the Google Hangout, but at some meetings I'm required to use Adobe Connect.

Answer (score -1):

Adobe Connect requires the following ports to be open all the time if using a non-SSL connection: `port 80, 443, and 1935 (RTMP traffic)`

If you organization has setup SSL, then all traffic goes through `port 443`.

Normally, `ports 80, 443` are open on my firewalls but a lot of firewalls do not know about `port 1935` and they have to be opened by the firewall administrator.

Also take a look [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/adobe-connect/kb/known-issues-connect-8.html) & [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/adobe-connect/kb/install-connect-meeting-add-ubuntu.html).

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you are proposing here. You mean port on the firewall in my company or my PC firewall? There is no problem on my company server, since I can share my screen from Windows. The problem is that Adobe discontinued support for Linux user after the Adobe Connect 8 (https://www.adobe.com/support/connect/downloads-updates.html?PID=3662453). The links you posted refers to Adobe Connect 8, but this product is old, and nobody is using it anymore.

Comment: I don't understand your answer: it is like you are answering a different question.